# Mysql getting error while using multiple joins with SUM method and if condition?

Tags: php, mysql

First query --

```
SELECT 
  SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'In', rm.messages, 0 ) ) AS `Added`
 ,SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'Out', rm.messages, 0 ) ) AS `Deduct`
 ,(SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'In', rm.messages, 0 ) ) - SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'Out', rm.messages, 0 ) )) AS `Actual Credit Balance Client Hold` 
FROM `resellers` AS `r`
LEFT JOIN `reseller_msg` AS `rm` ON `rm`.`reseller_id` = `r`.`resellerId`
INNER JOIN `panel_login` AS`p` ON `p`.`s_no` = `r`.`resellerId`
GROUP BY `rm`.`reseller_id`
ORDER BY `r`.`resellerId` DESC
```

On run first query it`s getting correct result like that -

```
username    Added   Deduct  Actual Credit Balance Client Hold   
pankaj123   1000    0       1000
soravgarg   1200    210     990
```

Second query --

```
SELECT
  `r`.`reseller_uname` AS `username`
 ,SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'In', rm.messages, 0 ) ) AS `Added`
 ,SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'Out', rm.messages, 0 ) ) AS `Deduct`
 ,(SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'In', rm.messages, 0 ) ) - SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'Out', rm.messages, 0 ) )) AS `Actual Credit Balance Client Hold`
FROM `resellers` AS `r`
LEFT JOIN `reseller_msg` AS `rm` ON `rm`.`reseller_id` = `r`.`resellerId`
INNER JOIN `panel_login` AS`p` ON `p`.`s_no` = `r`.`resellerId`
LEFT JOIN `user_msgs` AS `um` ON `um`.`reseller_id` = `r`.`resellerId`
GROUP BY `rm`.`reseller_id`
ORDER BY `r`.`resellerId` DESC
```

But using second query it's getting incorrect result like that -

```
username    Added   Deduct  Actual Credit Balance Client Hold   
pankaj123   1000    0       1000
soravgarg   7200    1260    5940
```

In second query I have added only a another join that is

```
LEFT JOIN `user_msgs` AS `um` ON `um`.`reseller_id` = `r`.`resellerId`
```

by adding this line in second query it's getting incorrect result; also we can see this in both second rows.

you can check also DB structure here --

http://appsms.in/sql/sms_panel

Comment: Can you format your post please. Use `{}` for code formatting.

Comment: @Rahul you can see below answer that is also in format..

Comment: and below answer is not working

Comment: Pls provide relevant source data as well. My guess is  that the extra join causes the records from the rm table to be duplicated in the resultset. But without seeing the source data it is difficult to modify your query. Moreover, you do not really use the user_msgs table in the output. Why do you include it anyway in the  query?

Comment: you can check also DB structure here --

http://appsms.in/sql/sms_panel

Comment: I still do not understand why you are adding the user_msgs table to tbe query if you are not using any fields from it in any calculation, nor in the output. Pls also provide the expected output as well.

Comment: @Shadow we will need also calculate In,Out type message from user_msgs table that`s why i am using...

Comment: Can you match user and reseller messages (e.g. for each reseller message there is a corresponding user message) or are these 2 completely independent from each other? If the messages can be matched, then describe how they can be matched.

Comment: finally i have resolved self..thank to everyone..

Comment: "it's getting incorrect result" - what is the result you do get? Please add it to the question, even if you have already resolved it. Please also add the answer below, so that if anyone else encounters the same problem, they can be helped by your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` as well

```
SELECT r.reseller_uname AS username, 
SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'In', rm.messages, 0 ) ) AS Added,
SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'Out', rm.messages, 0 ) ) AS Deduct,
(SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'In', rm.messages, 0 ) ) - SUM( IF( rm.rm_msg_type = 'Out', rm.messages, 0 ) )) AS `Actual Credit Balance Client Hold`
FROM resellers AS r 
LEFT JOIN reseller_msg AS rm ON rm.reseller_id = r.resellerId 
LEFT JOIN panel_login AS p ON p.s_no = r.resellerId      --    <-- This one
LEFT JOIN user_msgs AS um ON um.reseller_id = r.resellerId 
GROUP BY rm.reseller_id 
ORDER BY r.resellerId DESC;
```

Comment: sorry bro it`s getting same result..like that 
username  Added  Deduct  Actual Credit Balance Client Hold  
pankaj123  1000  0         1000
soravgarg  7200  1260  5940